# Signing PDF - PDF/3b compliance

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm trying to created a signed PDF/A-3b compliant PDF.

I've created a compliant PDF with iTextSharp and then after signing it is no longer compliant.  I'm using PdfAStamper with a trial certificate. When opening the document in Acrobat it displays a dialogue box alerting the user that it is a test certificate. Using Acrobat Pro Preflight to check compliance I get the following error:

- Name object is not a valid UTF-8 string

  - Some PDF based ISO standards require that all name objects are UTF-8 encoded.
- Document details

  - Trigger values

    - Name objects is UTF-8 encoded: is not true

      - { 1 0 obj/Prop_Build/App/Name }

Is it the dialogue box that is causing this error or is it something else?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of iText are you using? Didn't we fix this in a recent version? (If not, let me know and I hope we can still add it to the final sprint for the next release.)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It's v5.5.5.0

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I made a ticket on our issue tracker.