# Unable to add Signature Creator in itextSharp 5.5 /Prop_Build is not properly renderd

Tags: java, c#, pdf, itext, adobe

Unable to add **signature was created using**(signature creating application name) in the signature properties shown in adobe acrobat reader. In itextSharp 
if we set **SignatureCreator** property of **PdfSignature** class it will be rendered as **Prop_Build** tag in pdf but it is not properly rendered in **itextsharp**. however, it works fine in **itext java** is there any way to correct this issue.

this is c# code snippet used to sign pdf.

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace ItextDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pdfPath = "Test.pdf";
            string pfxPath = "Test.pfx";
            string pfxPassword = "TestPassword";
            int contentEstimated = 8192;
            X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(pfxPath, pfxPassword);
            using (MemoryStream Ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
                PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, Ms, '\0', null, true);
                PdfSignatureAppearance pdfSignatureAppearance = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;

                pdfSignatureAppearance.Reason = "Testing";
                pdfSignatureAppearance.Location = "Test location";
                pdfSignatureAppearance.Contact = "Prashanth";
                pdfSignatureAppearance.SignDate = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
                pdfSignatureAppearance.Acro6Layers = false;
                pdfSignatureAppearance.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED;
                pdfSignatureAppearance.Layer2Text = $"Name: {pdfSignatureAppearance.Contact}\nDate: {pdfSignatureAppearance.SignDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)")}\nReason: {pdfSignatureAppearance.Reason}\nLocation: {pdfSignatureAppearance.Location}";
                Rectangle signatureRectangle = new Rectangle(25, 725, 150, 785);
                pdfSignatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(signatureRectangle, 1, "Pdf signature");


                Dictionary<PdfName, int> exc = new Dictionary<PdfName, int>();
                exc[PdfName.CONTENTS] = contentEstimated * 2 + 2;
                PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
                dic.Reason = pdfSignatureAppearance.Reason;
                dic.Location = pdfSignatureAppearance.Location;
                dic.Contact = pdfSignatureAppearance.Contact;
                dic.Date = new PdfDate(pdfSignatureAppearance.SignDate);

                //Test creator is not present in /Prop_Build tag in pdf

                dic.SignatureCreator = "Test creator"; 
                pdfSignatureAppearance.CryptoDictionary = dic;
                pdfSignatureAppearance.PreClose(exc);
                Stream presignedStream = pdfSignatureAppearance.GetRangeStream();
                byte[] presignedBytes = ReadFully(presignedStream);
                byte[] sigbytes = SignDocument(presignedBytes, x509Certificate2);

                byte[] paddedSig = new byte[contentEstimated];
                Array.Copy(sigbytes, 0, paddedSig, 0, sigbytes.Length);
                PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
                dic2.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).SetHexWriting(true));
                pdfSignatureAppearance.Close(dic2);
                File.WriteAllBytes($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssfff")}Test.pdf", Ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the sample of pdf object generated

```
/Prop_Build<</App<</Name(Test creator)>>>>/ByteRange
```

hence in image given below we can clearly see that signature was created using is not available.

**sample image**

[image]

however, in java same code works and

```
/Filter/Adobe.PPKLite/Type/Sig/Prop_Build<</App<</Name/Test Creator>>>>/ByteRange
```

please find the image of the signature property where build property is properly rendered, and test creator is displayed.

**Sample image**

[image]

Comment: Essentially you found a bug. And it's present both in iTextSharp for .Net and in iText for Java. Originally both versions created a PDF Name there and both switched to using a PDF String. Probably you iText for Java merely is old enough not to include this "fix". Probably this issue was introduced in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29777819/1729265); that question doesn't ask for changing Name to String but merely encoding the name accordingly, but maybe the action to take was misunderstood when fixing this issue.

Comment: Some more details can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983330/signing-using-itext-adobe-reader-reports-signature-was-created-using-not-avail

Comment: I have added the fix in the answer can anyone verify that fix is correct

Answer (score 0):

this was fixed by adding the following method in class `iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.PdfSignatureAppDictionary`

```
PdfSignatureAppDictionary getPdfSignatureAppProperty()
{
    PdfSignatureAppDictionary appPropDic = (PdfSignatureAppDictionary)GetAsDict(PdfName.APP);
    if (appPropDic == null)
    {
        appPropDic = new PdfSignatureAppDictionary();
        Put(PdfName.APP, appPropDic);
    }
    return appPropDic;
}
```